# jquery prepend to body not working for me

Tags: jquery, prepend

I'm trying to use jquery to prepend a couple of hidden input tags to the start of the body of my JSP.

```
$("body").prepend('<input id="SCROLL_OFFSET_X" name="SCROLL_OFFSET_X" type="hidden" value="<%=myJSPPageVariableX%>"/>');
$("body").prepend('<input id="SCROLL_OFFSET_Y" name="SCROLL_OFFSET_Y" type="hidden" value="<%=myJSPPageVariableY%>"/>');
```

For some reason these are not appearing when I use firebug to view the HTML. Am I doing something wrong here?

Kind Regards,

Jason.

Comment: Are you making these calls during onload? i.e. `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`

Comment: prepend to the first element in the body: examplale the first div

Comment: Yes, this is called inside the document ready

Comment: Thanks all, sure enough I was doing something silly, there was a typo in my "$(document).ready(function() {" line. Doi!

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this question whilst having the same problem. I know this is a really old post, but I'm going to answer anyway.

Basically, you have to give the body tag a class, or better still, an ID, and use that as your selector. It's a shame you can't just use `body`, but we'll have to live without

Comment: That is not the case, at least in modern browsers.
`$('body').prepend('<p>hello</p>')` works fine, as does
`$('<p>hello</p>').prependTo('body')`

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't that result in visible html elements outside the body of the document?

Maybe that isn't allowed.

[Edit] The comments are correct, prepend appends inside the selected element.

Comment: I don't think so. `prepend` injects it as the first child element.

Comment: From the JQuery Documentation on prepend: prepend() "Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements."

Comment: I think that you're thinking of .before()